# Copy keyword breaks numpy's copy/view philosophy

Tags: python, scipy, copy, sparse-matrix

I have noticed that none of the methods that are used to convert between types of sparse matrices are using `copy` kwarg, supplied in the the method. Even though, copying in most cases actually happens, the `data` array (where it is valid) always has a `base` set, which means that it shows up as a `view` in the code. However, de facto the copy has been made.

Is this an intentional behavior?

For instance, here are examples of with `csr` and `csc` arrays. As you can see, all of them have bases, no matter what.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: from scipy import sparse
   ...: 
   ...: a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
   ...: csr = sparse.csr_array(a, copy=True)
   ...: print('csr.data.base', id(csr.data.base) if csr.data.base is not None else None)
   ...: 
   ...: csr_copy = csr.copy()
   ...: print('csr_copy.data.base', id(csr_copy.data.base) if csr_copy.data.base is not None else None)
   ...: 
   ...: csc_copy = csr.tocsc(copy=True)
   ...: print('csc_copy.data.base', id(csc_copy.data.base) if csc_copy.data.base is not None else None)
   ...: 
   ...: csc_copy_2 = csr.tocsc()
   ...: print('csc_copy_2.data.base', id(csc_copy_2.data.base) if csc_copy_2.data.base is not None else None)
csr.data.base 4392865488
csr_copy.data.base 4392866448
csc_copy.data.base 4392866640
csc_copy_2.data.base 4392867120
```

While it makes sense for `csr_copy` to have the same `base` as `csr.data`, I don't understand why any other objects have `base` attribute set for data to begin with.

In particular, this behavior prevents user from direct manipulation with `data` and `indices` parameters of the array. For instance, it becomes, impossible extend `csr` matrix, by adding rows to it using inplace `resize` method:

```py
In [2]: old_nnz = csr.nnz 
   ...: row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Lets append row of 5 elements to csr
   ...: 
   ...: csr.resize(5, 5)
   ...: 
   ...: print(id(csr.data))
   ...: print(csr.data)
   ...: 
   ...: print(id(csr.data.base))
   ...: print(csr.data.base)
   ...: 
   ...: csr.data.resize((old_nnz + len(row),), refcheck=True)
4757413808
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
4757413520
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3433, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-c52e3457494e>", line 12, in <module>
    csr.data.resize((old_nnz + len(row),), refcheck=True)
ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
```

While using `np.resize` might work, I am not sure how inplace it is:

```py
In [3]: old_nnz = csr.nnz 
   ...: row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Let's append row of 5 elements to csr
   ...: 
   ...: csr.resize(5, 5)
   ...: 
   ...: print('Data')
   ...: print(id(csr.data))
   ...: print(csr.data)
   ...: 
   ...: print("Data's Base")
   ...: print(id(csr.data.base))
   ...: print(csr.data.base)
   ...: 
   ...: print('New Data')
   ...: new_data = np.resize(csr.data, (old_nnz + len(row),))
   ...: print(id(new_data))
   ...: print(new_data)
   ...: 
   ...: print("New Data's Base")
   ...: print(id(new_data.base))
   ...: print(new_data.base)
   ...:
   ...: new_indices = np.resize(csr.indices, (old_nnz + len(row),))

Data
5256251600
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
Data's Base
5256250736
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
New Data
5256250928
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  1  2  3  4  5]
New Data's Base
5256253040
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

I have been reading the source code for these functions and I don't see `copy` even used in some of those. For instance,
in [_csr.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/sparse/_csr.py):

```py
def tocsc(self, copy=False):
    idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices),
    maxval=max(self.nnz, self.shape[0]))
    indptr = np.empty(self.shape[1] + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    indices = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    data = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))

    csr_tocsc(self.shape[0], self.shape[1],
        self.indptr.astype(idx_dtype),
        self.indices.astype(idx_dtype),
        self.data,
        indptr,
        indices,
        data)

    A = self._csc_container((data, indices, indptr), shape=self.shape)
    A.has_sorted_indices = True
    return A
```

Even though I see that new array (`data`) is created, somewhere down the line, maybe somewhere between C/Python interface it is put into `base`.

Comment: SciPy does not promise that the backing arrays of the new sparse matrix with `copy=True` will own their data. It promises that the new sparse matrix *won't* share any backing storage with the original sparse matrix.

Comment: Very little in NumPy or SciPy actually promises to create an array that owns its data.

Comment: Thank you! I I have to agree with you, however, in their documentation, they specifically distinguish between the two cases, so I guess, I thought I could rely on it. But I ultimately figured a better way around it anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I only have scipy v 1.7.3, so don't have access to the major rewrite of the sparse module in 1.8 (e.g. not `csr_array` or `_data.py` file).

Whether something has a `base` or not is not a reliable measure of whether a copy was made.  Take your first example:

```
In [74]: a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
    ...:   ...: csr = sparse.csr_matrix(a, copy=True)

In [75]: a
Out[75]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [76]: a.base
Out[76]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])
```

`a` is a `view` of the 1d array produced by the `arange`.  That array is not accessible - except as the `base`.

```
In [77]: csr
Out[77]: 
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The `data` attribute has a `base` - that looks the same as itself.  `id` is different.  But we'd have to study the code to see how `data` was derived from its `base`.

```
In [78]: csr.data
Out[78]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19], dtype=int32)

In [79]: csr.data.base
Out[79]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19], dtype=int32)
```

It isn't a `view` of `a` or `a.base`, as we can prove by modifying an element.

```
In [82]: csr.data[0] = 100

In [83]: csr.A
Out[83]: 
array([[  0, 100,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19]], dtype=int32)

In [84]: a
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

The `copy` parameter makes most sense when keeping the same format.  Changing format can involve reordering the data (csr to csc), or summing duplicates (coo to csr), etc.

Let's try making a new `csr`:

```
In [87]: csr1 = sparse.csr_matrix(csr, copy=False)
In [88]: csr2 = sparse.csr_matrix(csr, copy=True)
```

As with `csr`, both of these have `data.base` and different ids.  But if I modify an element of `csr`, that change only appears in `csr1`. `csr2` is indeed a copy.

```
In [93]: csr.data[1] = 200
In [97]: csr1.data[1]
Out[97]: 200
In [98]: csr2.data[1]
Out[98]: 2
```

### resize

I haven't used `resize` before for sparse, and rarely use it for `numpy`.  But playing with the `csr`, it's evident it's quite a different operation.

`csr.resize(5,5)` appears to just change the `indptr` (and `shape`), without change to `data` or `indices`.

`csr.resize(5,6)` just seems to change the `shape`.  I don't see a change in main attributes.  Neither adds nonzero values, so "padding" with 0s doesn't change much.

You don't want to do `csr.data.resize(...)`.  Such a change would also require changing `indices` and `indptr` (to maintain a consistent `csr` format).  `data` can have 0s, but it should be cleaned up with a call to `eliminate_zeros`.

### ravel

The sparse code could be doing something as harmless as `ravel`.

```
In [129]: x = np.array([1,2,3]).ravel()
In [130]: x.base
Out[130]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [131]: x.resize(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [131], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x.resize(4)

ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
```

Another example where `base` is not a reliable indicator of `copy/view`, is when indexing columns (of a 2d array):

Make a 2d array, which has its own data:

```
In [144]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [145]: arr.base             # None
```

A row selection also has a `None` base:

```
In [146]: arr[[1]].base
```

But a column selection does not - even though it is a copy:

```
In [147]: arr[:,[1]].base
Out[147]: array([[2, 4]])    
In [148]: arr[:,[1]]
Out[148]: 
array([[2],
       [4]])
```

Evidently the indexing operation selects a (1,2) array, which is then reshaped to (2,1).  Actually, looking a `strides`, I think it's doing a transpose.  `arr[:,[1]].base.T`.