# Retrieving values of a CSR matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

### Question

I have a CSR matrix, and I want to be able to retrieve the column indices and the values stored.

### Data

For different reasons I'm not allowed to share my data, but here's a look (the `numpy` library is imported as `np`):

```py
print(type(data) == type(ind) == list)  # data and ind are lists 
# OUT: True

print(len(data) == len(ind) == 134464)  # data and ind have a size of 134,464
# OUT: True

print(np.alltrue([type(subarray) == np.ndarray for subarray in data]))  # data (and ind) contains ndarray
# OUT: True

print(np.alltrue([len(data[i]) == len(ind[i]) for i in range(len(data))]))  # each ndarray of data have the same length than the corresponding ndarray of ind 
# OUT: True

print(min([len(data[i]) for i in range(len(data))]) >= 1)  # each subarray of data (and of ind) has at least a length of 1
# OUT: True

print(np.alltrue([subarray.dtype == np.float64 for subarray in data]))  # each subarray of data (and of ind) contains floats
# OUT: True
```

### Code

Here is how I create the matrix (using `csr_matrix` from `scipy.sparse`):

```py
indptr = np.empty(nbr_of_rows + 1)  # nbr_of_rows = 134,464 = len(data)
indptr[0] = 0
for i in range(1, len(indptr)):
    indptr[i] = indptr[i-1] + len(data[i-1])  
data = np.concatenate(data)  # now I have type(data) = np.darray, data.dtype = np.float64 and len(data) = 2,821,574
ind = np.concatenante(ind)  # same than above

X = csr_matrix((data, ind, indptr), shape=(nbr_of_rows, nbr_of_columns))  # nbr_of_columns = 3,991 = max(ind) + 1 (since min(ind) = 0)

print(f"The matrix has a shape of {X.shape} and a sparsity of {(1 - (X.nnz / (X.shape[0] * X.shape[1]))): .2%}.")
# OUT: The matrix has a shape of (134464, 3991) and a sparsity of 99.47%.
```

So far so good (at least I think so). But now, even though I manage to retrieve the column indices, I can’t successfully retrieve the values:

```py
print(np.alltrue(ind == X.nonzero()[1]))  # Retrieving the columns indices
# OUT: True

print(np.alltrue(data == X[X.nonzero()]))  # Trying to retrieve the values
# OUT: False

print(np.alltrue(np.sort(data) == np.sort(X[X.nonzero()])))  # Seeing if the values are at least the same
# OUT: False

print(np.sum(data) == np.sum(X[X.nonzero()]))  # Seeing if the values add up to the same total
# OUT: False
```

When I look deeper, I find that I get *almost* all the values (only a small amount of mistakes):

```py
print(len(data) == len(X[X.nonzero()].tolist()[0]))
# OUT: True

print(len(np.argwhere((data != X[X.nonzero()]))))
# OUT: 2184
```

So I get "only" 2,184 wrong values out of 2,821,574 total values.

Can someone please help me in getting all the correct values from my CSR matrix?

### EDIT

I know now thanks to @hpaulj that I can use the class attributes `X.indices` and `X.data` to retrieve the CSR format index array and the CSR format data array of the matrix. However, I still would like to know why, in my case, I don't have `np.altrue(X[X.nonzero()] == X.data)`.

Comment: `X.data` and `X.indices` should both be array `nnz` long.

Comment: Wow thanks @hpaulj, I feel dumb not thinking about the fact that the csr_matrix class from scipy.sparse had to have these attributes. Well, I feel like it might still be a bug that `X.data != np.asarray(X[X.nonzero()]).ravel()` but anyway, your solution is very helpful and solves my problem so thank you for your answer!

Comment: ` X.nonzero` gets row/col from the COO format.  Even if count is the same, the data order may differ.

Comment: The match with `ind`  indicates that order and number is not an issue.  But without your `data` I can't explore further.  You should check dtypes.  And if it is float, use `np.allclose` to compare float arrays.

Comment: I have `data.dtype == X[X.nonzero()].dtype == np.float64`. And I checked for some random indices (I knew by using `np.argwhere((data == X[X.nonzero()]) == False)` the list of indices `i` for which the values in both arrays were not the same and the results were very different (for example `data[385] = 3.` and `np.asarray(X[X.nonzero()]).ravel()[385] = 5.`). So I have identical `dtypes` and the two arrays are not element-wise equal within a small tolerance (my values in `data` and in `X[X.nonzero()]` go from `.1` to `264.`). Obviously, `np.allclose(X[X.nonzero()], data)` is `False`.

Comment: `ind = np.concatenante(ind).ravel  # same than above` is the missing `()` a typo?

Comment: Yes it was a typo but I completely removed it from my code since it was unnecessary. Now, I simply have `data = np.concatenate(data)` and `ind = np.concatenate(ind)`, which still gives me the same thing (`data` and `ind` are both numpy arrays of float64). I also think that I constructed `indptr`, `ind` and `data` correctly, since I do have `len(data) = len(ind) = indptr[-1]` with `indptr[0] = 0` and `len(indptr) = nbr_of_rows + 1`.

Comment: Do you have any duplicates in the `ind` sublists?  Duplicates are summed at some point, usually when converting from `coo` to `csr`.  I don't know when that happens when the input is `indptr` style.  You might test if the `sum_duplicates` method makes any change.  `prune` and `check_format` may also help.

Answer (score 1):

Without your `data` I can't replicate your problem, and probably wouldn't want to do so even with such a large array.

But I'll try to illustrate what I expect to happen when constructing a matrix this way.  From another question I have a small matrix in a Ipython session:

```
In [60]: Mx
Out[60]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [61]: Mx.A
Out[61]: array([[0, 1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

`nonzero` returns the `coo` format indices, row, col

```
In [62]: Mx.nonzero()
Out[62]: (array([0, 0], dtype=int32), array([1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

The csr attributes are:

```
In [63]: Mx.data,Mx.indices,Mx.indptr
Out[63]: 
(array([1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Now lets make a new matrix, using the attributes of `Mx`.  Assuming you constructed your `indptr`, `indices`, and `data` correctly this should imitate what you've done:

```
In [64]: newM = sparse.csr_matrix((Mx.data, Mx.indices, Mx.indptr))    
In [65]: newM.A
Out[65]: array([[0, 1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

`data` matches between the two matrices:

```
In [68]: Mx.data==newM.data
Out[68]: array([ True,  True])
```

`id` of the `data` don't match, but their bases do. See my recent answer to see why this is relevant

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74543855/901925

```
In [75]: id(Mx.data.base), id(newM.data.base)
Out[75]: (2255407394864, 2255407394864)
```

That means changes to `newA` will appear in `Mx`:

```
In [77]: newM[0,1] = 100
In [78]: newM.A
Out[78]: array([[  0, 100,   2]], dtype=int32)
In [79]: Mx.A
Out[79]: array([[  0, 100,   2]], dtype=int32)
```

### fuller test

Let's try a small scale test of your code:

```
In [92]: data = np.array([[1.23,2],[3],[]],object); ind = np.array([[1,2],[3],[]],object)
    ...: indptr = np.empty(4)  
    ...: indptr[0] = 0
    ...: for i in range(1, 4):
    ...:     indptr[i] = indptr[i-1] + len(data[i-1])
    ...: data = np.concatenate(data).ravel()    
    ...: ind = np.concatenate(ind).ravel()  # same than above

In [93]: data,ind,indptr
Out[93]: (array([1.23, 2.  , 3.  ]), array([1., 2., 3.]), array([0., 2., 3., 3.]))
```

And the sparse matrix:

```
In [94]: X = sparse.csr_matrix((data, ind, indptr), shape=(3,3))    
In [95]: X
Out[95]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`data` matches:

```
In [96]: X.data
Out[96]: array([1.23, 2.  , 3.  ])

In [97]: data == X.data
Out[97]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

and is infact a `view`:

```
In [98]: data[1]+=.23; data
Out[98]: array([1.23, 2.23, 3.  ])    
In [99]: X.A
Out[99]: 
array([[0.  , 1.23, 2.23],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [3.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

### oops

I made an error in specifying the `X` shape:

```
In [110]: X = sparse.csr_matrix((data, ind, indptr), shape=(3,4))

In [111]: X.A
Out[111]: 
array([[0.  , 1.23, 2.23, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 3.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])

In [112]: X.data
Out[112]: array([1.23, 2.23, 3.  ])

In [113]: X.nonzero()
Out[113]: (array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))

In [114]: X[X.nonzero()]
Out[114]: matrix([[1.23, 2.23, 3.  ]])

In [115]: data
Out[115]: array([1.23, 2.23, 3.  ])

In [116]: data == X[X.nonzero()]
Out[116]: matrix([[ True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @hpaulj. So I can see that by imitating the way I construct `indptr`, `indices`, and `data`, and then by creating your CSR matrix with the "standard representation" (just like me), you obtain `np.alltrue(data == X[X.nonzero()])`, which is not the case for me. I looked at what could possibly cause this (like having an empty array in `data` or in `ind` before the concatenation or having the same value twice or more in the same subarray of `ind` also before the concatenation) but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the values you store in the matrix, `numpy.float64` or `numpy.int64`, perhaps, the following post might answer your question: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13329#issuecomment-753541268

In particular, the comment "*Apparently I don't get an error when data is a numpy array rather than a list.*" suggests that having `data` as `numpy.array` rather than a `list` could solve your problem.

Hopefully, this at least sets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for linking this related GItHub issue that I wasn't aware of @radof. However, as I commented on the 5th line of my first block of code, `data` is already a `numpy.darray` (it was a list of numpy.darray that I concatenated to join and then ravelled to transform to a contiguous flattened array). At the end I have `len(data) == len(np.asarray(X[X.nonzero()]).ravel())` and `data.dtype == np.asarray(X[X.nonzero()]).ravel().dtype == np.float64`.